# About recursive function in merge sort

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort

I was trying to understand the step by step(all the things that goes under the hood and every little detail) of the merge sort algorithm implemented by recursive function. However, I really don't understand what is going on in the following function, which i found from Geeks for geeks. so as far as i know, recursive function are recursively called until the base case is reached and it returns to the caller. however, in this function, the following questions still are on my mind:

1. what is the base case here?
2. after the recursive call reaches the base case( in this case I think mergesort(singledigit), aren't we supposed to return something?
   I don't really know what kind of question I should ask, as the whole idea of recursion is confusing me. please help.

It would make more sense to explain this recursion by going through and explaining the ff example?
**for example my current understanding is that, let arr=**[4,2,7,9,12,3,1,5]
then recursive call would be in ff order
merge(arr)->merge([4,2,7,9])->merge([4,2])->merge([4])
but since the len(4)<=1, it doesn't get in the if clause of the ff function, which means it does go past the two lines of mergesort() function calls. then it proceeds with merge(2), which will make it the same. finally, there won't be the sorting. this definitely shows that i am misunderstanding the flow of excution. so i would appreciate if someone could go through an example(like use the array above) to explain the step by step of the excution. thank you in advance.

```
def mergeSort(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1:
       # print("This is funny to be honest",arr[0],len(arr))
        mid = len(arr)//2
        print("This is funny",arr,arr[0],len(arr))
        L = arr[:mid]
        R = arr[mid:]
        mergeSort(L)
        mergeSort(R)
        i = j = k = 0
        while i < len(L) and j < len(R):
            if L[i] < R[j]:
                arr[k] = L[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                arr[k] = R[j]
                j += 1
            k += 1

        # Checking if any element was left
        while i < len(L):
            arr[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1

        while j < len(R):
            arr[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1
```

Comment: The base case here is clearly when `len(arr) <= 1`  :)

Comment: Base case is `len(arr) <= 1`. the sorting is happening in place - so nothing is returned, the original array is modified

Comment: if the base case is len(arr)<=1, how can this ever excute the while loop? for example, if we take merge([3,1,5,2]), the flow would be(if i am not mistaken) merge([3,1])->merge([3]) and since len([3]) <=1, it doesn't go to the while loop and it goes to merge(5,2) and the same thing happens, which finally makes it do nothing. of course this is a very wrong understanding by me, so i would appreciate if someone could go through the step by step for a certain array

Comment: @Solruhama no no no, it does not go to the while loop. the _whole_ of the function body is inside that `if`. if the length is 1 or 0, nothing happens. the function just returns without doing anything at all. why? because an array of length 0 is already sorted, and so is an array of length 1. _any_ such array.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens other than the recursive function splitting arrays into two sub-arrays and calling itself until two sub-arrays of size 1 are produced. At that point, those sub-arrays are merged to create a sorted run of size 2. Then the sort follows the call chain up and down, depth first, left first, merging runs of ever increasing size, until it gets to the initial call where two sorted runs are merged back into the original array.

Note that top down merge sort is mostly academic. Most libraries implement a stable sort as a hybrid of insertion sort and bottom up merge sort, such as Timsort.

Answer (score 0):

Base case is `len(arr) <= 1` in which case `mergeSort(arr)` does nothing. Its input `arr` is already a sorted array -- whether its length is 0, or 1. Nothing to sort there.

And in general `mergeSort(arr)` does not return any value. It just returns. But it does change its argument array, `arr`. See all those `arr[k] = ...` statements? That's what they are doing, placing new elements into the array's entries, one by one:

```
mergeSort [4,2,7,9,12,3,1,5]
= { arr = [4,2,7,9,12,3,1,5],       ...                             }
= {L := [4,2,7,9], R := [12,3,1,5], ...                             }
= {mergeSort L,                              mergeSort R, merge_loop}
= {{L = [4,2,7,9], ...                    }, mergeSort R, merge_loop}
= {{LL := [4,2], LR := [7,9], ...         }, mergeSort R, merge_loop}
= {{mergeSort LL, mergeSort LR, merge_loop}, mergeSort R, merge_loop}
= {{{LL = [4,2], ...                         }, mergeSort LR, merge_loop}, mergeSort R, merge_loop}
= {{{LLL := [4], LLR := [2], ...             }, mergeSort LR, merge_loop}, mergeSort R, merge_loop}
= {{{mergeSort LLL, mergeSort LLR, merge_loop}, mergeSort LR, merge_loop}, mergeSort R, merge_loop}
= {{{{LLL = [4]},   mergeSort LLR, merge_loop}, mergeSort LR, merge_loop}, mergeSort R, merge_loop}
= {{{LLL = [4],   {LLR = [2]},     merge_loop}, mergeSort LR, merge_loop}, mergeSort R, merge_loop}
= {{{LLL = [4],    LLR = [2],      merge_loop}, mergeSort LR, merge_loop}, mergeSort R, merge_loop}
= {{{LL[0] := 2, LL[1] := 4                  }, mergeSort LR, merge_loop}, mergeSort R, merge_loop}
= {{LL = [2,4], {mergeSort LR                              }, merge_loop}, mergeSort R, merge_loop}
= {{LL = [2,4], {LRL = [7], LRR = [9], ...                 }, merge_loop}, mergeSort R, merge_loop}
= {{LL = [2,4], {mergeSort [7], mergeSort [9], merge_loop  }, merge_loop}, mergeSort R, merge_loop}
= {{LL = [2,4], {LRL = [7],     LRR = [9],     merge_loop  }, merge_loop}, mergeSort R, merge_loop}
= {{LL = [2,4], {LR[0] := 7,  LR[1] := 9                   }, merge_loop}, mergeSort R, merge_loop}
= {{LL = [2,4],  LR = [7,9],                                  merge_loop}, mergeSort R, merge_loop}
= {{L[0] := 2, L[1] := 4, L[2] := 7, L[3] := 9                          }, mergeSort R, merge_loop}
= {L = [2,4,7,9], {mergeSort R                                      }, merge_loop}
= .......
= {L = [2,4,7,9], {{RL[0] := 3, RL[1] := 12}, ...                   }, merge_loop}
= .......
= {L = [2,4,7,9], {RL = [3,12], {RR[0] := 1, RR[1] := 5}, merge_loop}, merge_loop}
= {L = [2,4,7,9], {RL = [3,12], RR = [1,5],               merge_loop}, merge_loop}
= {L = [2,4,7,9], {R[0] := 1, R[1] := 3, R[2] := 5, R[3] := 12      }, merge_loop}
= {L = [2,4,7,9],  R = [1,3,5,12],                                     merge_loop}
= {arr[0] := 1, arr[1] := 2, arr[2] := 3, arr[3] := 4, 
   arr[4] := 5, arr[5] := 7, arr[6] := 9, arr[7] := 12                           }
= {arr = [1,2,3,4,5,7,9,12]                                                      }
```

You wanted to understand the whole chain of function calls, and that's hard. We use recursion precisely so that we don't have to do that, so we can solve our problem *easily* instead.

The way to understand a recursive function is first of all to assume that it works correctly.

This means we can use it whenever we need to solve a problem of the kind it expects.

This seems circular. After all `def solve(x) : { solve(x) }` gets us nowhere.

The trick is to use our function to solve *smaller* subproblems of our original problem. We already "know" it works correctly. We just need to combine the solved subproblems somehow so that our original problem gets solved. *This* is the non-trivial step.

Specifically, after splitting the array `arr` into the two halves, `L` and `R`, we *know* both are smaller in size than the original array `arr`. Thus we *"know"* that after calling `mergeSort(L)`, `L` is now sorted. And similarly for `R`.

And the non-trivial step is the merge. *Assuming* `L` and `R` are already sorted before the `while` loop, it is easy to see that `arr` will be filled by its original elements *in the sorted order* after the `while` loop has finished.

And that's that.

Or is it? Well, we have the *base* case to consider, the array `arr` which is so small that it can't be split into halves. That's no problem though, as such an array is *already sorted*.

Thus the assumption holds for the smallest size arrays, and it also holds for a bigger arrays because the merge works correctly under the assumption that our function works correctly for the smaller sizes.

Thus is works for our input array, *whatever* its size is.

In other words it works for any array. Thus it works for all of them.

This is known as "induction": A. we prove that a property holds for a *base* case; B. we prove that the *combination* step preserves that property; thus C. that property holds for any bigger case which we solve by combining the solutions found for its smaller subproblems that are similar in nature to the original problem:

```
solve(X --> R) :  
    isBase(X) --> baseResult(X --> R).
solve(X+Y --> R) :  
    solve(X --> A), 
    solve(Y --> B),
    combine( (A,B) --> R ).
```

Comment: I think you should try to answer the specific question asked instead of talking a general idea about it.

Comment: I don't think that I _should_ have to do that, esp. that I did address the specifics already, but nevertheless I did elaborate on that.